# How to send file in JAVA via POST without saving it to disk

Tags: spring, post, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I need to send file to a POST service from the server side code.
The content of the file I need to send is in String format.
I don't want to create the file in the disk.
I can't find the way to send file without creating it in the disk.

I prefer **not to create a TEMP file** but this is what I managed to do.

**How do I send file without saving it to disk, not even as TEMP file?**

This is the code:

```
    String fileContent = generateFile();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.add("apikey","myapikey");

    File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("test", ".tmp");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tmpFile);
    writer.write(fileContent);
    writer.close();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tmpFile));
    reader.close();

    FileSystemResource fsr = new FileSystemResource(tmpFile);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body
            = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("file",fsr);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
            = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    String serverUrl = "https://api.com/api";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
            .postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);

    return response.getBody();
```

POSTMAN screenshot that I use to test the API and it works perfect

[image: POSTMAN Body]

[image: POSTMAN Headers]

Comment: I personally prefer to use `byte` data type for this kind of use cases. And parsing it to relevant data type in server and client side.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question

Comment: @user1913615  After sending a file, do you want to prase?

Comment: I mean if you can handle server side (where you send the POST request), take byte array as an input and then convert it to required data type.

Comment: @Avijit Barua, no.

Comment: @Rauf Agayev I can convert the data to any type even byte array, the question is how do I send it as File without creating a real file in the computer.

Comment: @user1913615 Please post your complete controller. You posted inner code. Complete code will help us to understand completely

Answer (score 2):

Use a [ByteArrayResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html) instead:

```
String fileContent = generateFile();
ByteArrayResource bar = new ByteArrayResource(fileContent.getBytes());
```

This way you will not have to create any resource on disk but keep it in memory instead.